# IntelliJ Preview RecyclerView api level 25

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-recyclerview

I've been facing a bit of a problem lately and have yet to find a solution to this.

I want to create a `RecyclerView` but the preview function in intelliJ (latest version) is throwing me this error when I use the latest SDK/BuildTools/appCompat/design. Here is the error:

```
Exception raised during rendering: Unable to locate mode 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate mode 0
at android.view.DisplayInfo.findMode(DisplayInfo.java:423)
at android.view.DisplayInfo.getMode(DisplayInfo.java:410)
at android.view.Display.getRefreshRate(Display.java:640)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.java:2392)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2836)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:238)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:359)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:652)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:155)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.lambda$flush$1(MergingUpdateQueue.java:260)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:274)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:229)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:222)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:378)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.run(Alarm.java:389)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.SchedulingWrapper$MyScheduledFutureTask.run(SchedulingWrapper.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.runFirstTaskThenPollAndRunRest(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:178)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$000(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:40)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:197)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is my `build.gradle` file :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.dle.medtrack"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'

}
```

After hours of trying different versions around I managed to find one where the preview works. I get the same error when trying it in Android Studio 2.2.2.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.dle.medtrack"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'


    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception raised during rendering: Unable to locate mode 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161934/exception-raised-during-rendering-unable-to-locate-mode-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved with the latest update from intelliJ

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in 25.0.0 (I'm experiencing it as well - annoying), and it is actually being tracked here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225753

**Issue 225753: RecyclerView - Rendering Problems - Exception raised during rendering: Unable to locate mode 0**

Star the issue to keep informed of updates.