# Exception raised during rendering: Unable to locate mode 0

Tags: android, android-studio

After update `BuildTools` to version 25.0.0.

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25"
```

I have problem with android layout preview. Now it show error:

> Exception raised during rendering: Unable to locate mode 0

[image]

I tried to Clean & Rebuild project, but it doesn't work.
Before update everything was good.

I know that I can go back to previous versions of `BuildTools`, but I want to know why it doesn't work on version `25.0.0`?

---

Seems like it is a problem with `RecyclerView`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate mode 0
at android.view.DisplayInfo.findMode(DisplayInfo.java:458)
at android.view.DisplayInfo.getMode(DisplayInfo.java:445)
at android.view.Display.getRefreshRate(Display.java:648)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.java:2392)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:15392)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2953)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:333)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$53(RenderTask.java:659)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug with 25.0.0. I've opened an issue for it:  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225753&thanks=225753&ts=1476988808

Comment: I get the same issue with compileSdkVersion 24 / buildToolsVersion "24.0.2" - however I let Android Studio do an update (of various things, essentially what ever it asked to update) yesterday, and I believe it was broke after that.

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa Problem arising when https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Rubin left #Google

Answer (score 111, accepted):

This [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225753) has been resolved, update the support library to

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```

Answer (score 62):

It's an Annoying bug of version 25..
A Temporary solution is to downgrade your project,

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
```

Answer (score 18):

Another temporary solution is to replace `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` with `<RecyclerView` so you can see the rendered View. When compiling, change it back to `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`

Answer (score 7):

> The Android Support Library provides backward-compatible utility
>   functions. Apps can use these utility functions to provide an
>   appropriate user experience across a wide range of Android system
>   versions.

It's a **[bug](https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html)** issue and should be fixed in the future **[Release of the support-design library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)**.

- **[Rendering Problems - Exception raised during rendering: Unable to locate mode 0](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225753&thanks=225753&ts=1476988808)**

You should ***downgrade*** your version for ***Temporary Solutions*** .

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:v7:25.0.1' 
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
```

Answer (score 6):

To see preview I use this trick.....
add  `app:layoutManager="0"` for the recyclerView in a layout XML

But it will throw InflateException at run time. So **REMOVE** this property from XML layout file before running the app!

Answer (score 4):

As temp solution you can create child class of recycler view and override only onAttachedToWindow as below. Then use this class in your XML layouts

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
    }
}
```

Update: starting from support library 25.0.1, fix already included in the library and issue not exist anymore