# Rendering issue in XML preview : Unable to locate mode 0

Tags: android, exception, android-xml, illegalstateexception

After updating the android studio exception occured during rendering.

> Exception raised during rendering: Unable to locate mode 0

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate mode 0
at android.view.DisplayInfo.findMode(DisplayInfo.java:458)
at android.view.DisplayInfo.getMode(DisplayInfo.java:445)
at android.view.Display.getRefreshRate(Display.java:648)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.java:2392)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:15392)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2953)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:333)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$53(RenderTask.java:659)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Known issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161934/exception-raised-during-rendering-unable-to-locate-mode-0

Comment: Issue has been resolved. Update Support Library to the new version.             
 `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'`
 `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'`
 `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'`

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'   it will work..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's problem with RecyclerView in `com.android.support:design:25.0.0`

Maybe there is some issue in that version.
Changed version to 24.1.1 solved my problem.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
```

in case you not have not removed the default provided gradle imports change this also

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
```

Comment: I wonder if the com.android.support developers use Andriod Studio at all...

Comment: This is so crazy! Are they even testing it once before shipping? *sigh* Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You can also use version `24.2.1`, which is the latest version before `25.0.0`

Answer (score 5):

Either downgrade to v24

OR

The following is neither a solution nor a work around.

If you ONLY want to see the PREVIEW, add app:layoutManager="0" for the recyclerView in a layout XML.

Adding this will throw runtime InflateException. So, please remove that property from XML layout file before running the app.

Comment: So why not use tools:layoutManager="0"?

Answer (score 3):

Just change your compileSdkVersion to 24 and downgrade the dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
```

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

A Temporary solution is to downgrade your project,

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
```

Comment: please edit the existing answer instead of subbmitting an other one with almost the same content.

Comment: Not a solution if you require 25, for BottomNavigationView for example

Comment: @TonyBenBrahim yes, just a temporary fix when you are editing layout files. The proper fix will probably come with an update to the support repositories.